# HTML/CSS Flex column & Flex row with same width size

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to get the same width size for my horizontal & vertical butons.
I used **flex-basis** (which by the way doesn't work for me in the code snipet here...) but the problem is flex-basis in column mode will adjust the height and not the width.
What would be a better way to do it ?

```css
#adjustButonVertical {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 20px;
}

#adjustButonHorizontal {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  top: 0px;
  left: 10%;
}

#adjustButonHorizontal>* {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 200px;
}

#adjustButonVertical>* {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="adjustButonHorizontal">
    <button id="buton1" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">buton1</button>
    <button id="buton2" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">buton2</button>
    <button id="buton3" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">buton3</button>

    <div id="adjustButonVertical">
      <button id="buton4" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">buton4</button>
      <button id="buton5" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">buton5</button>
      <button id="buton6" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">buton6</button>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What height do you want them (all) to have? Should it be an explicit width, or should the 'vertical' buttons have whatever height the 'horizontal' buttons have, or vice versa?

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you work along the x and y axis, I'd recommend you use [CSS Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/) This way, you can position the buttons explicitly using `grid-row: [selected lines]` or `grid-column: [selected lines]`. This method would allow you to adjust the precise size of the grid in each position, easily controlling the width.

You would require a 3x3 grid that can be easily achieved through creating a wrapper div and applying the following CSS:

1. `display: grid`
2. `grid-template-column: repeat(3, 1fr);`
3. `grid-template-row: repeat(3, 1fr)`

Then select your buttons in CSS and position them using `grid-row:` and/or `grid-column:`. If you are new to CSS grid and position, watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9zBsdzdE4sM&ab_channel=WebDevSimplified) by Web Dev Simplified

Another possible (and quicker but less well maintainable solution) is to select `<div id="adjustButonHorizontal">` and set a fixed width, with the child button set to `width: 100%`. Keep in mind this is *not responsive design* and will likely break when using different devices. Take advantage of CSS grid's [fractional units](https://css-tricks.com/introduction-fr-css-unit/)!

Answer (score 0):

I would just use a text element for the text that has the rotating button and then use a `transform` to rotate the text. This allows for the text to not determine the width of the button, therefore matching the sizes.

```css
#adjustButonVertical {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  top: 20px;
}

#adjustButonHorizontal {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  top: 0px;
  left: 10%;
}

#adjustButonHorizontal>* {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 200px;
}

#adjustButonVertical>* {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: 200px;
  width: 20px;
}

button>p {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="adjustButonHorizontal">
    <button id="buton1" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">buton1</button>
    <button id="buton2" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">buton2</button>
    <button id="buton3" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">buton3</button>

    <div id="adjustButonVertical">
      <button id="buton4" class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><p>buton4</p></button>
      <button id="buton5" class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><p>buton5</p></button>
      <button id="buton6" class="btn btn-primary" type="button"><p>buton6</p></button>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```